# PhpStorm doesn't recognize methods that are not in the interface

Tags: php, methods, interface, phpstorm, contract

```
<?php

interface iFoo {
    public function print(): iFoo;
}

class Foo implements iFoo {
    public function print(): iFoo {
        return $this;
    }

    public function chain(): iFoo {
        return $this;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->print()
    ->chain() // Method 'chain' not found in iFoo
    ->print();
```

How can I make PhpStorm recognize the chain method, even though it's not in the contract?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're telling PHPStorm that you're going to have a return type of iFoo which doesn't have the class `chain()` if your return type is `Foo` I would guess this would work.

Comment: It wouldn't because it doesn't match the contract, also I can't set Foo as return type in the interface.

Answer (score 1):

`print()` method returns `iFoo` instance:

```
public function print(): iFoo {
```

`iFoo` does not contain `chain()` method, that's why you see "method not found". You can change the return type to `Foo` or add `chain()` method to `iFoo`.